# Apache XSSF Workbook conflicting package errors

Tags: java, excel, apache

So I am receiving error messages as the XSSFWorkbook import appears to be incompatible with the final line.  The code as it is gives the error message that package "org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook" does not exist.  When I remove the import, the last line then gets the error message that I should create an XSSFWorkbook class.  I am currently using the Apache 3.7 utilmodel file in order to import the XSSFWorkbook class.  Any help would be most appreciated.  I am trying to create a program that reads data from an excel file.

```
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Sheet;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Workbook;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;



public class ReadExcel {

    private static final String FILE_PATH = 
 "/Users/riveraaz/Desktop/FantasyPros_2015_Overall.numbers";           

    public static List getPlayersFromExcel() {
        List PlayerList = new ArrayList();
        FileInputStream fis = null;
        try {
            fis = new FileInputStream(FILE_PATH);
            Workbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(fis);
```